# python list comprehension and multiple variables

Tags: python

I'd like to condense my code into a single line.

```
p = ['https://mysitea.com', 'https://mysiteb.com']
x =  []
for i in p:
    x.append(f"https://{i}/oauth2/idpresponse")
    x.append(f"https://{i}/auth")
```

Is it possible to perform it using list compression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `chain.from_iterable` from `itertools` on each pair of strings

```
from itertools import chain

x = list(chain.from_iterable((f"https://{i}/oauth2/idpresponse", f"https://{i}/auth") for i in p))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do this is to maintain a list of paths and one of actions and then merge them into one single list  compression which has two for nested loops.

```
hosts = ['https://mysitea.com', 'https://mysiteb.com']
actions = ['/oauth2/idpresponse', '/auth']

[host+action for host in hosts for action in actions]
```

Prints

```
['https://mysitea.com/oauth2/idpresponse',
 'https://mysitea.com/auth',
 'https://mysiteb.com/oauth2/idpresponse',
 'https://mysiteb.com/auth']
```

Comment: agreed 100%. I'd nitpick that you should probably be more descriptive than `for x in p for y in a` and instead err towards something more like `for host in hosts for action in actions`

Comment: You are right and I made the switch. Thanks for the remark

Answer (score 1):

You can use `if-else` in `list compression` to do it.But I'm sure there is a better way to do it.

code:

```
p = ['https://mysitea.com', 'https://mysiteb.com']
print([f"https://{i}/oauth2/idpresponse" if idx%2 == 0 else f"https://{i}/auth" for idx,i in enumerate(p*2)])
```

result:

```
['https://https://mysitea.com/oauth2/idpresponse', 'https://https://mysiteb.com/auth', 'https://https://mysitea.com/oauth2/idpresponse', 'https://https://mysiteb.com/auth']
```

**EDIT**:a better way with use `sum`

code:

```
print(sum(([f"https://{i}/oauth2/idpresponse",f"https://{i}/auth"] for i in p),[]))
```

result:

```
['https://https://mysitea.com/oauth2/idpresponse', 'https://https://mysitea.com/auth', 'https://https://mysiteb.com/oauth2/idpresponse', 'https://https://mysiteb.com/auth']
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't care the sequence of items in list, you can do like this:

```
["https://%s/oauth2/idpresponse" % i for  i in p] + ["https://%s/auth2/idpresponse" % i for i in p]
```